# Integrate google map direction with 8 + way points in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have requirement to integrate google map api with multiple waypoints.

Available data I have is array of latitude , longitude & timestamp. say :

```
$scope.locations = [
{latitude : 22.152454, longitude:88.455454 , timestamp:"21451457451"},
{latitude : 32.152454, longitude:88.44554 , timestamp:"21451457451"},
{latitude : 12.152454, longitude:88.875454 , timestamp:"21451454451"},
{latitude : 54.152454, longitude:88.8755454 , timestamp:"21521457451"}
]
```

Now I want to have google map displayed in my application with markers showing datetime of waypoints.

I tried [ngmap](https://ngmap.github.io) but this dosen't support more then 8 points also I didnt found it much effective .

Answer (score 0):

If you're not limited in using AngularJS, this [sample](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/directions-waypoints) from the Google Maps API developer site seems to fit with what you want to do.